Is color charge internal symmetry or global symmetry?
I was told the color charge in the standard model could not be observed directly. This sounded like the gauge field $\vec A$ in the electromagnetism. However, it is a discrete charge and does have indirect physical observable effect. But the permutation of the color charge was again ambiguous, unlike the electric charge that could be isolated.
The internal/gauge/local symmetry reflect to the recrudescence in the lagrangians and does not have physical effect. (The Aharonov-Bohm Effect was the potential field done after fixing the gauge.)
Is color charge internal/gauge/local symmetry or global symmetry?

For a gauge theory where the symmetries are not spontaneously broken, the local symmetry and be restricted to a global symmetry. For a system of quarks and gluons there is a globally conserved colour current, but it is a colour vector, not a simple number. Additionally because of chromodynamics, all physical semi-stable states are colourless, and so it is not a particularly useful quantum number to build a conserved current out of, because on reasonable time and length scales it is zero.

I would prefer to say that $SU(3)$ is an internal gauge symmetry, and color charge is not physically observable because it is not gauge invariant. The permutations of colors you mentioned is one example of a gauge transformation: more generally, you could consider superpositions of color states, and any choice of orthogonal color states forms a basis and has the right to be called "red, green, blue".
